# Trading item cards to another player that already has 5

Tags: forbidden-island

On a player's turn can they give an item card to another player that already has 5 cards? Would that player just have to discard a card or is it not allowed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may only have 5 cards at any given moment. If you share a treasure card (or cards) with a player that already has 5, that player must immediately discard down to 5.